# Is this the reason as to why the change of basis formula is the way it is?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

For two basis B and B', the change of basis formula is:

$$e'_i=c^j_i e_j$$

My question is, is it defined this way because ultimately every vector of B' can be written as a linear combination of the vectors of B?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Thank  you, this way it is much easier for me to unwrap linear algebra.

Comment: further, you should use $c^j{}_i$ to keep the tracking of who is row and who is column

Comment: I personally prefer to refer to the change-of-basis matrix, whose column vectors are the coordinates of the new basis vectors written in terms of the old basis. That is the matrix is $[c_i^j]$, where $i$ denotes the column and $j$ denotes the row. So be very careful. Note how @janmarqz spaced things.

Comment: yes! first index: rows, second index: columns

Comment: @janmarqz Oh, I do that, but I just didn't know how to write it in LaTeX.

Comment: this way: c^j{}_i

Comment: Thanks, I'm new with the processor so tips like those are great.